# Load Image From Database With Asynchronous

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

What i have so far in Class

```
  public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmap(string ConnectingString, string SQLCode)
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectingString);

        //Open Connection String
        con1.Open();

        // load image from the database 
        SqlCommand Commandcmd = new SqlCommand(SQLCode, con1);
        Task<BitmapImage> t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();


            SqlDataReader rdr1 = null;
            rdr1 = Commandcmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (rdr1.Read())
            {
                if (rdr1 != null)
                {
                    if (rdr1[0] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        byte[] data = (byte[])rdr1[0]; // 0 is okay if you only selecting one column

                        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
                        {

                            // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
                            myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
                            myBitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                            myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            myBitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 500;
                            myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 500;
                            myBitmapImage.EndInit();
                            myBitmapImage.Freeze();

                        }
                        return myBitmapImage;
                    }


                }

            }

            return myBitmapImage;

        });

        await t;
        return t.Result;
    }
```

in and what i use in event is :

```
MyImage.Source = await s.GetBitmap(PublicVar.ConnectionString, "SELECT (UserImage) FROM Users WHERE UserID = " + id);
```

But when it gonna work my program give me error 
its text is 
'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
i can make it fix by Dischapter.Invoke 
But Really it is not async .
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `Task.Run` but use the asynchronous ADO.NET methods:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmap(string ConnectingString, string SQLCode)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectingString);
    //Open Connection String
    await con1.OpenAsync();
    // load image from the database 
    SqlCommand Commandcmd = new SqlCommand(SQLCode, con1);
    BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    SqlDataReader rdr1 = null;
    rdr1 = await Commandcmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    while (await rdr1.ReadAsync())
    {
        if (rdr1 != null)
        {
            if (rdr1[0] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                byte[] data = (byte[])rdr1[0]; // 0 is okay if you only selecting one column
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
                {

                    // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
                    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    myBitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                    myBitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 500;
                    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 500;
                    myBitmapImage.EndInit();
                    myBitmapImage.Freeze();
                }
                return myBitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }
    return myBitmapImage;
}
```

`Task.Run` will execute the specified action on a thread pool thread and you can't access UI controls from any other thread than the dispatcher thread that they were originally created on.

Answer (score -1):

You can even go further and read the blob as a stream. Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support).